# Does $\mathrm{adj}(A)=\mathrm{adj}(B)$ imply $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If $A$ and $B$ are any two square matrices of same order and if $\mathrm{adj}(A)=\mathrm{adj}(B)$, does it imply $A=B$?

I am pretty sure if $A$ and $B$ are invertible and if $A^{-1}=B^{-1}$, then $A=B$.

So is it true for Adjoint?

Comment: @Widawensen made a mistake, I'm deleting that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed

if $A^{-1}=B^{-1} $ then $AA^{-1}B=AB^{-1}B$  i.e.  $B=A $.

If  $A,B$ are non-invertible then $\det(A)=\det(B)=0$ and
$\text{adj}(A)A=\det(A)I=0$ and $\text{adj}(B)B=\det(B)I=0$.

This can be satisfied without $A=B$.

Hence counterexamples for supposed theorem are, for example

$\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 0 \ \end{bmatrix}$,
$\begin{bmatrix}  0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 0 \ \end{bmatrix}$.

Here of course $\text{adj}(A)=\text{adj}(B)$.

Comment: So the examples you have taken are actually singular matrices right? Now if we consider two Non singular matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $adj(A)=adj(B)$  $\implies$ $A^{-1}|A|=B^{-1}|B|$ and taking inverse on both sides we get $A=\frac{|A|}{|B|}B$ that is $A$ is scalar multiple of $B$. Hence if adjugate's of two non singular matrices are equal, then one of them is scalar  multiple of other.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma  with non-singular matrices when $A=kB$ the only possibility is $k=1$ because it follows that they have equal determinants  (as Farrukh has shown)  - so their inverses are equal and $A=B$ .

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma However I have now some little doubts about Farukh's completness of the answer for case $k=-1$ which can arise when $n$ is odd  ..Because :$\text{adj}(-  {A}) = (-1)^{n - 1}\text{adj}( {A}) $ then $\text {adj}(A)=\text{adj}(B)$ for odd n.. in this case evidently it can follow also $A=-B$..

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma So my final conclusion is that for odd $n$ (dimension) from equality of adjugates follows $A=B$ or $A=-B$. For even $n$ only $A=B$..

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma The easiest way to check above statement  is to take identity matrix $I$ and $-I$. You will see that adjugates of these matrices are equal when dimension is odd.

Comment: ok according to Farrukh's answer when $n$ is odd we get $|A|=\pm |B|$, from this i could not get why you are concluding that $A=-B$ only

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma  You know that $\det(A)  A^{−1}=\text{adj}(A)$    and $\det(B) B^{−1}=\text{adj}(B)$ . But we assuming  $\text{adj}(A)=\text{adj}(B)$ and for this case $ \det(A)=\pm\det(B) $
  then $A^{−1}=\pm B^{−1}$ . Now you can use transformation from the first line of my answer to get $ A=\pm B $

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma See examples 

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $  ,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $  ,

$\text{adj}(A)= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  ,
$\text{adj}(B)= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  ,

$\det(A)=1$ $ \ \ $,
$\det(B)=-1$ $ \ \ $,

$ A^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$  $ \ \ $,
$ B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$  $ \ \ $.

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma So you see that in this case from adj(A)=adj(B) we have $A=B$ **or** ("or" doesn't mean "only") $A=-B$.

Comment: yes now clear thanks

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Thank you Ekaveera for interesting question.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The adjugate matrix is basically the wedge power $\wedge^{n-1} A$ if $n$ is the dimension of the underlying vector space. If the underlying field has nontrivial $(n-1)$-th roots of unity, then we can multiply $A$ by one of them without changing the adjugate matrix. Also, the adjugate matrix of any matrix of rank $< n-1$ will be $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. It is given: $adj(A)=A^{-1}|A|=adj(B)=B^{-1}|B|$. Multiply both sides by $A$, then $B$ to get: $A=\frac{|A|}{|B|}B$. It implies: $$|A|=\left(\frac{|A|}{|B|}\right)^n|B| \Rightarrow \left(\frac{|A|}{|B|}\right)^{n-1}=1\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
|A|=|B|, \  \  \  \ \ if \ n \ is \ even \\ 
|A|=\pm|B|,  \ \ if \ n \ is \ odd
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Well done Farrukh, so we have equality of determinants and following equality of inverses for invertible matrices...

Comment: However   it seems that for $n$ odd as a final conclusion can be also  made $\vert A \vert = -\vert B \vert$

Comment: @Widawensen, thank you. Updated.

Comment: Ok. Farrukh,  now we have a complete answer for Ekkaveera, it seems..