# Properties of matrices changing with the parity of matrix dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Lately I encountered a situation when particular property of a real square matrix depended on the **parity** of matrix dimension, namely:

- for **even** dimension from  [equality of adjugates  of invertible
  matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311831/does-mathrmadja-mathrmadjb-imply-a-b) we can infer about equality of matrices, for **odd**
  dimension there is no equivalence ( *i.e. matrix function $B=\text{adj}(A)$ is bijective in the set of non-singular matrices only for even dimensions*)

The other well known situation when  the parity of   matrix dimension also matters is the situation for skew-symmetric matrices:

- only even-dimensional skew-symmetric matrices can have full rank.

**Question:**
What are the other situations when some property of a real square matrix is alternating due to the changing dimension parity?

Maybe somewhere is a list of such properties?
If there is no general list single examples will be also good as the answer ... at least one additional example...

*Edit*
I'm adding the next property

- only for even dimensions the equation $A^2=kI$ where $k <0$ has a
  solution in real numbers (more accurately: infinite number of solutions) - lack of solution for odd $n$   follows immediately from $\det(A^2) \geq 0 $  and $det(kI)=k^n$.

Comment: I don't know if this is really what you're looking for, but the *groups* of matrices $$\textrm{SO}_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{ x \in \textrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) : xx^t = I \}$$ are quite different for $n$ even or odd.

Comment: @D_S Yes, if they are quite different that is what I'm looking for, But what do you regarding as 'quite different' ? There is a difference between $n=2$ and $n=3$, but what is the general difference between odd and even $n$ ...?

Comment: Their root systems are in different classes.  The "four classical semisimple groups" are $$\textrm{SL}_n, \textrm{Sp}_{2n}, \textrm{SO}_{2n}, \textrm{SO}_{2n+1}$$ so the odd and even orthogonal groups can be considered as different from each other as they are from $\textrm{SL}_n$.  I can post a more detailed answer if you want.

Comment: @D_S Very interested in.. all details are welcome..

Comment: "only even-dimensional skew-symmetric matrices can have full rank" - this of course extends to all matrices with eigenvalues appearing in $\pm$ pairs, e.g. skew-centrosymmetric matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be an involutory matrix, i.e. $K^2 = I$, and let the matrix $A$ be a skew-centrosymmetric $K$-matrix, i.e. $A$ anti-commutes with $K$:
$$
AK = -KA.
$$
If $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$ s.t.
$$
A v = \lambda v,
$$
then
$$
\lambda K v = K A v = K A K K v = - A K v,
$$
i.e. $(-\lambda, Kv)$ is also an eigenpair of A. Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ come in $\pm$ pairs, so if the dimension of $A$ is odd, then $A$ must have a zero eigenvalue. Hence, only even-dimensional skew-centrosymmetric $K$-matrices can have full rank.

**Edit**

The same argument may be applied in the case where $AK = -KA^\top$ by noting that $A$ and $A^\top$ have the same eigenvalues. This includes skew-symmetric ($K=I$) and skew-persymmetric ($K=J$, where $J$ is the exchange matrix) matrices as special cases.

Comment: Very interesting property, thank you.. what about skew-persymmetric?, I have checked by example calculations that probably  the case may be similar ( if zeros are on the antidiagonal) - the eigenvalues also come in $\pm $ pairs..

Comment: Since the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^\top$ are the same, we can use an identical argument as above to obtain the same result for any matrix satisfying $AK = -KA^\top$. Then, skew-persymmetry corresponds to $K = J$, where $J$ is the exchange matrix, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, you are right. If you would like you may add your comment to your answer, it would make it richer.. unfortunately as I've already  upvoted your answer I can't do this second time as it deserves..

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I have updated the answer as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

From another thread:

If $p$ is a polynomial without real roots, and $A$ is a real matrix with odd dimension, then $p(A) = 0 $ never holds.

This follows mainly from the fact that odd degree real polynomials always have a root.

Comment: Thank You Raul for the answer, If it would happen that you know also other properties which depend on parity of matrix dimension, don't hesitate - add them here..

Answer (score 1):

The response here can be regarded as a follow-up to ekkilop’s fine answer.  It can be viewed as a generalization of that answer, and remains pertinent to the question being asked.

Let the term *$m$-involution* mean any complex square matrix $K$ for which $K^m=I$, where $m$ is an integer greater than $1.$  The usual involutory matrix case corresponds to the situation where $m=2.$  One question we may ask is, for a given square matrix $A$, what can we say about the set of $m$-involutory matrices that anti-commute with it?  Let’s denote this set as $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$.

Given $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n},$ it is possible to establish the following result:

1. Let $n=1$. If $A$ is the number zero, then $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ contains the $m$-th roots
   of unity.  Otherwise, $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is empty.
2. Suppose $n>1$ and let $m>1$ be an odd integer.  If $A$ is the zero matrix, then
   $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is non-denumerable.  Otherwise, $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is empty.
3. Suppose $n>1$ and let $m>1$ be an even integer.  If the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$
   come in pairs of opposite sign where the corresponding pairs have Jordan blocks of equal size,
   then the cardinality of the set $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is non-denumerable.
   Otherwise $\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is empty.

Characterizing the sets to be empty or non-denumerable for $n>1$ may seem to be a rather weak statement, but note that this result contrasts, for example, with the set of $m$-involutions that *commute* with a fixed diagonalizable matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with distinct eigenvalues in which the case the cardinality of the set is $m^n.$

Note that the first and third cases together imply ekkilop’s observation.  For the third case with $m=2$, if $n$ is odd then if $A$ is non-singular the Jordan blocks corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ cannot all be paired up as positive - negative pairs of equal size.  In other words, if $n$ is odd and $A$ is non-singular, then  $\tilde S_2\left( A \right)$ must be empty: i.e., there are no involutory matrices $K$ that can anti-commute with $A$.  Therefore, if $n$ is odd and $A$ anti-commutes with some involutory matrix $K$, then $A$ must be  singular.

The theorem quoted above is trivial to prove for the first two cases.  For the second case, we can simply observe that for an $m$-involutory matrix $K$ that anti-commutes with $A,$ we have that $A = K^mA = (-1)^mAK^m = (-1)^mA$, so if $m$ is odd it then follows that
$\tilde S_m\left( A \right)$ is empty except when $A$ is the zero matrix.

For the third case, the argument is somewhat more involved.  For that demonstration, the interested reader can find a proof in the paper [*"Some properties of commuting and anti-commuting m-involutions*”](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0252960212600447?via%3Dihub).  Perhaps more interesting is that this paper's Lemma 5.1, which is the main observation used in the proof, can be used to construct $m$-involutory matrices $K$ that anti-commute with a given matrix $A$, provided such $K$ exist.